# How do I order an array in ruby when ordering has four different conditions?

Tags: ruby

I am not sure how I can re-order an array based on two booleans in Ruby.  I would like to order my results in the following order:

```
* Note awkward ordering *
1) is_strong: true, requires_api_check: false
2) is_strong: true, requires_api_check: true
3) is_strong: false, requires_api_check: true 
4) is_strong: false, requires_api_check: false
```

And I wrote some pseudocode to return the correct order, but this won't work. I realize I can only return -1,0,+1, but I'm not sure how to handle this situation.

```
objects = [
            OpenStruct.new(is_strong: false, requires_api_check: false),
            OpenStruct.new(is_strong: false, requires_api_check: true),
            OpenStruct.new(is_strong: true, requires_api_check: false),
            OpenStruct.new(is_strong: true, requires_api_check: true),
        ]


      objects.sort do |res|
        if res.is_strong
          if !res.requires_api_check
            1
          else
            2
          end
        else
          if res.requires_api_check
            3
          else
            4
          end
        end
      end
```

Comment: It's probably not the most efficient way but it can be done through concatenation: `objects.select(&:is_strong).sort_by(&:requires_api_check).reverse + objects.reject(&:is_strong).sort_by(&:requires_api_check)`

Comment: With [`sort_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) instead of `sort`, your solution works as is.

Comment: `sort` yields two compared objects to the block and expects a value of `< 0`, `0` or `> 0`. This allows you to define custom sorting rules between potentially unrelated objects. `sort_by` on the other hand yields only a single object to the block. Whatever is returned from the block is then used for comparison. If you return Integers there, your final array will be sorted by these raw Integer values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `sort_by` which is available on Arrays through the [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) module.

`sort` yields two compared objects to the block and expects a value of `< 0`, `0` or `> 0`. This allows you to define custom sorting rules between potentially unrelated objects.

`sort_by` on the other hand yields only a single object to the block. Whatever is returned from the block is then used for comparison. If you return Integers there, your final array will be sorted by these raw Integer values.

Thus, given your "awkward" sorting rules, your code works fine if you use `sort_by` instead of `sort` without having to express your rules in terms of [spaceship-operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-way_comparison) rules.

In the example below, I just shortened your code a bit with ternary operators.

```
objects.sort_by do |res|
  if res.is_strong
    res.requires_api_check ? 2 : 1
  else
    res.requires_api_check ? 3 : 4
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Since there seems to be no perceivable logic, hard-coding AWKWARD_ORDERING  is the way to go:

```
require "ostruct"

AWKWARD_ORDERING = [[true, false],[true,true],[false,true],[false, false]]

objects = [
            OpenStruct.new(is_strong: false, requires_api_check: false),
            OpenStruct.new(is_strong: false, requires_api_check: true),
            OpenStruct.new(is_strong: true, requires_api_check: false),
            OpenStruct.new(is_strong: true, requires_api_check: true),
        ]

p res =  objects.sort{|obj| AWKWARD_ORDERING.index([obj.is_strong, obj.requires_api_check])}
```

Comment: Hardcoding the ordering is a good idea. However, since `sort` yields the two compared objects (in comparison to `sort_by` whose interface you seem to expect here), your code will fail with a `NoMethodError: undefined method `is_strong' for Array`.

Comment: @HolgerJust It does not return a NoMethodError  on my Ruby (2.4) nor on http://ideone.com/gliFFS .

Comment: I would understand what you are doing if `sort` were replaced by `sort_by`. `sort` obviously works but the documentation for [Array#sort](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-sort) says that if there is a block the block must compare two values and return a negative, zero or positive value. @HolgerJust used the same form of `sort`. Please elucidate.

Comment: Hmm, seems like `sort` does indeed not pass an array of elements to the block but only as many as the blocks arity. That said, your code is still incorrect since `sort` works different from `sort_by`. It doesn't blow up but still doesn't sort correctly.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Meh, missed the copy & paste error in the code of my answer :( Of course, only `sort_by` is correct in this context. Sorry for the confusion...

Comment: @HolgerJust, @CarySwoveland  `sort` and `sort_by` deliver the same results for me in this case ( as in  ==). Could be a coincidence - but I don't get it.

Comment: I am perplexed. `obj` takes a single value (e.g., `"#<OpenStruct is_strong=false, requires_api_check=false>"`, not a pair. Moreover, `sort`'s block always returns a non-negative value. It's as though Ruby's parser saw something causing it to use `sort_by` here. Can anyone explain what's happening here.?

Comment: @CarySwoveland It might be an artefact (in lieu of calling it a bug) of how the block is called in MRI that it still works with one value. Still, when checking the block's return value, Ruby is just checking if the value is smaller than 0, larger than 0 or exactly 0. The exact value is not important. Thus, for most values (apart for `[true, false]`), the code states that the given value is larger than the other ignored one which results in a strange sort order due to the inconsistent returns. This becomes more apparent for larger input-arrays.